# How to get previous year in php?

Tags: php

I've a format date like this

```
$y = date('Y');
```

so the output is **`2015`**

but if I try getting previous year using the below code:

```
$yr = date('Y'($y,'-1 year'));
echo $yr;
```

I get incorrect output. The output is **`1970`**.

How to get the previous year?

Comment: @JJ-SAMA, have a look at the small function I have posted to make your life a little less complicated. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't using any library which does `natural language processing`. A better option will be to do

```
$y = date('Y') - 1;
```

Also, I am worried about the syntax: `date('Y'($y...`

> EDIT

Exactly as I expected, your code doesn't even compile: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(' in /scratchpad/index.php on line 3`

Try creating a function which does this:

```
function getYear( $before = 0 ) {

    return ( date( 'Y' ) - $before );

}
```

Even better is to use `strtotime`:

```
function getYear( $context ) {

    return date( 'Y', strtotime( $context ) );

}
```

Then use it something like:

```
echo ( getYear( '-1 year' ) );
```

will give: `2014`.

Comment: Pleasure! :) // extra stuff to fix the min comment limit

Comment: @JJ-SAMA, be sure to accept the answer as it'll close this question and people will know that it has an accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function

```
<?php
 echo date('Y', strtotime('-1 Year'));
?>
```